# Unexpected behavior of bootstrap photo gallery

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to display photos of group members (Count 30) in matrix form using html, css, bootstrap.But some of photos are getting displaced from their original position to next block, leaving the block empty.(All the photos are of same aspect ratio).This is the basic block :-

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="team-member">
    <!-- Memebr Photo, Name & Position -->            
        <div class="member-photo">
        <a href="#"><img alt="Name" src="Img.jpg"></a>
            <div class="member-name"> Member_Name       <span>style="width: -moz-max content;">Member_info</span>
            </div>        
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Running the code is a bit inconclusive can you post a small screen capture?

Comment: There's an extra `>` in the span tag before the style declaration. Typo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest using this template:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68721417,width-643,imgsize-1016106,resizemode-4/nature1_gettyimages.jpg"
                     class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```